# I try to change the button class and icon upon clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, icons

I try following javascript code in the click event, but its not works.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btnHideItemAdjustment"> <i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>Hide Adjustments</button>'

('.btnHideItemAdjustment').on('click',function (e) {

    $(e.target).removeClass('btnHideItemAdjustment').addClass('btnShowItemAdjustment').text('Show Adjustments');
    $(e.target).find('i').removeClass("icon-chevron-up").addClass("icon-chevron-down");
});
```

Comment: The code given is not enough to tell where the problem lies.. Please update it with your html code as well as the code for click event.

Comment: I have added in more code. Thanks.

Comment: The text button changes ok, but the icon disappear.

Comment: There is no element in your html code with class `.btnShowInvoiceItems` that triggers the click event.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. I have corrected it. But the code isn't not working. The text is change just fine, but not the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not working because you substitute the `<i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>Hide Adjustments` part with `Show Adjustments` and this is why the element `i` is not accessible when you try to remove/add class in the next line. I used `e.currentTarget` and not `e.target` because `e.currentTarget` always references to the `btnHideItemAdjustment` element whereas `e.Target` can sometimes refer to the `span` element that has the text for the button depending on where you clicking.

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btnHideItemAdjustment"> <i class="icon-chevron-up"></i><span>Hide Adjustments</span></button>

 $('.btnHideItemAdjustment').on('click',function (e) {
            $(e.currentTarget).removeClass('btnHideItemAdjustment').addClass('btnShowItemAdjustment').find('span').html('Show Adjustments');
            $(e.currentTarget).find('i').removeClass("icon-chevron-up").addClass("icon-chevron-down");
        });
```